# Is Microsoft Graph API/ MS Bot Framework provide direct read receipt functionality for messages sent by bots

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is Microsoft Graph API/ MS Bot Framework provide direct read receipt functionality for messages sent by bots:
I want to check, the number of users who have read those messages.

I have checked this answer which says we can't do with graph api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1111770/is-it-possible-to-check-read-receipts-using-graph

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team, we will let you know once we get any updates on it.

Comment: We are actively checking this with engineering team, we will update you soon.

Comment: Hello @Vikash - Just for your information, Read Receipt functionality is going to release soon with MS Bot Framework but we don't have exact ETA to share.